# What is tsr file

Tags: file, export, tsr

i have a requirement to export data to tsr file only. Previously we used to export to csv file.

Can anyone tell me what is tsr file and what is the content format? Is the contents in someway  similar with csv?

Comment: Do you mean the DOS relic - Terminate and Stay Resident programs?

Comment: @Oded: It seems it is not the TSR you are referring to. It is associated with some export of data.

Comment: @Oded: No, it's is not related with the DOS relic.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not [come up](http://www.computerfileextensions.com/file-extensions.php/TSR) with something convincing. I suggest you ask your client to explain the requirement in more detail. TSR does not seem to be a generally understood format.

---

*Maybe TSV (tab-separated values, VERY similar to CSV)?*

Answer (score 1):

TSR are shared repository file. Basically you can see this type of file in HP UFT. Whenever you create object in UFT it goes into repository with extension .tsr.

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://www.computerfileextensions.com/file-extensions.php/TSR

But the results are not so clear/convincing.

Can not you ask for a sample tsr file from your client?

Answer (score 0):

Another result for related to TSR files, but it's probably another format the OP was looking for.

> The TSR file extension is related to TSR Launcher, a fan-made program for The Sims 3 computer game series that allows users to quickly install Sims3Pack files without using the Launcher provided by EA. It looks like the program is no longer available for download.
>
> A *.tsr file is used for download basket function. Most likely some sort of container.

http://www.file-extensions.org/tsr-file-extension

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.